# How to enforce array entries to be keys in a record in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, interface, key

I want to define a TypeScript interface like this:

```js
interface ObjectSchema {
  properties: Record<string, any>;
  required: Array<string>;
}
```

but with the added constraint that entries of `required` should be keys of `properties`. How do I go about this?

A validly typed object would be:

```js
let schemaA = {
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {},
  },
  required: ["foo"]
}
```

A invalidly typed object would be:

```js
let schemaA = {
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {},
  },
  required: ["baz"] // "baz" isn't a key in properties.
}
```

Comment: I think you could just loop over the entries of your required array and for each string you find, you can check if your properties object has a property with that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two type variables must be used, one for the keys of `properties`, one for the subset of said keys for `required`.

`asObjectSchema` is just a convenient function to exploit the inference, so we don't have to annotate the type variables.

```
interface ObjectSchema<A extends string, B extends A> {
  properties: Record<A, any>
  required: Array<B>
}

const asObjectSchema = <A extends string, B extends A>(
  schema: ObjectSchema<A, B>
): ObjectSchema<A, B> => schema

const schemaA = asObjectSchema({
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {},
  },
  required: ['foo'],
})

const schemaB = asObjectSchema({
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {},
  },
  required: ['baz'], // Type '"baz"' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar"'
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgMoIAWEAtnADwCCyEAHpCACYDOyzYUoA5gDTIBCNehCatKAPmQBvAFDJkABygB7BdDDAIzAFzIASjmVRGVPnBABPcXORQIARwCuwO412UoUOBfL9rAXxkZBGUQdmQ4ZgxsXAJiMmQAXmQqIQYWNg5uPkE6dLFxAAobZiJSOF1onHwyslMBawBKSqxquPL6vyTJUvi4IJCwsDZauGpkyKrY0cLZeSVVdU0daRt5GGVlXSl-HjXkdDgobd2bU-k7JxcIN2QAbQByDeUHgF09-0aB0PDe8sEJlFWtM+rMbAs1FANFptvtnic9vJ5IdjtJzsh0ZdnK5dI9DgAvN58AD0xOQABULGpkA8AEQE2kPZDAVggZTDSLMYBcEBwdAAGxQYGUyDAVJQdOetOQAB9kPSjoyZJ8gA)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. An [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67402049/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: You're right @jcalz, thank you for pointing this out. I edited my answer, what do you think now?